# What is the difference between timeout and error in XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

Can somebody please explain me when error and ehen timeout error will be raised.
I put timeout here for `PUT` request but in what use case will be called `onTimeout` and in what `onError` handlers?

```
return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("PUT", url);

    xhr.timeout = 10000;

    xhr.onreadystatechange = async function() {
       ....
    }
    xhr.ontimeout = function() {
      // Time out.
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() {
      // Some error
    };
}
```

Comment: timeout is when you request a server and the request doesn't receive a response for some defined time (expire time). error is when you recieve an error message as a response when something went wrong on server/other side.

Comment: How can I simulate timeout to test will it fire after 10sec?

Comment: test what @1110

Comment: also your code is not quite OK. You shouldn't use Promise and async/await like this. 

if you go for promise use `return new Promis((resolve,reject)=>{})` and if you use async use it like this `return async function() {}` and use await for other promises to resolve. maybe that's giving you trouble also. `return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {` <= this is just wrong.

Comment: To test will timeout handler fire after 10sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `XMLHttpRequest.timeout` property is an unsigned long representing the number of milliseconds a request can take before automatically being terminated. The default value is 0, which means there is no timeout. Timeout shouldn't be used for synchronous `XMLHttpRequests` requests used in a document environment or it will throw an InvalidAccessError exception. When a timeout happens, a timeout event is fired.

Despite the request timeout `onerror` method fires right after server has sent the error response. For example, if your server is shut down your `timeout` method will be fired after 10 seconds.

More info: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout)